# Proving that $f(\bar Z)\subset\overline {f(Z)}$ when $f$ is a continuous map

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to solve this question from my textbook:

> Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map and let $Z \subset X$.
>   Prove the inclusion $f(\bar Z)\subset\overline {f(Z)}$.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hint: let $y$ in $f(\overline Z)$ then $y=f(x)$ for some $x$ in $\overline Z$. By definition of $\overline Z$ this means that...

Comment: I think the marked duplicate is for the converse, not what is being asked here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$Z\subset f^{-1}\left(\overline{f\left(Z\right)}\right)$ and as preimage
of a closed set $f^{-1}\left(\overline{f\left(Z\right)}\right)$ will
be closed because $f$ is continuous. Then $\bar{Z}\subset f^{-1}\left(\overline{f\left(Z\right)}\right)$
so $f\left(\bar{Z}\right)\subset\overline{f\left(Z\right)}$.